# OpenGL ES 2.0 vbo white screen

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I have been trying to get my game engine to work on android and I got stuck at vertex buffer arrays. It works using FloatBuffer, but when I tried to render with VBOs I only got a white screen. So I was wondering if there is something wrong with my code.

This is how I create the VBOs:

```
private int[] vbo = new int[1];
private int[] ibo = new int[1];

private void setUpVBO()
{
    short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices
    float TextureCoords[] = 
    { 
    0.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
    0.0f, 1.0f,   // top left
    1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
    1.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
    };
    float squareCoords[] = { 
                -width / 2.f - 0.015f / 2.f,  height / 2.f + 0.015f / 2.f, 0.0f,   // top left
                -width / 2.f - 0.015f / 2.f, -height / 2.f - 0.015f / 2.f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
                 width / 2.f + 0.015f / 2.f, -height / 2.f - 0.015f / 2.f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
                 width / 2.f + 0.015f / 2.f,  height / 2.f + 0.015f / 2.f, 0.0f }; // top right
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        ByteBuffer tc = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(TextureCoords.length * 4);
        tc.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer TextureCoordinateBuffer = tc.asFloatBuffer();
        TextureCoordinateBuffer.put(TextureCoords);
        TextureCoordinateBuffer.position(0);


        // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        ShortBuffer drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);


        GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, vbo, 0);
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, ibo, 0);

        if (vbo[0] > 0 && ibo[0] > 0) 
        {
            GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
            GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer.capacity() * 4,
                    vertexBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
            GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TextureCoordinateBuffer.capacity() * 4,
                    TextureCoordinateBuffer, GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);


            GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo[0]);
            GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, drawListBuffer.capacity()
                    * 2, drawListBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
}
```

This is how I render:

```
public void render(float[] mMVPMatrix) 
{       
    if (vbo[0] > 0 && ibo[0] > 0) 
    {
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(Values.mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(Values.mPositionHandle, Values.COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                Values.fullStride, 0);


        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(Values.mTextureCoordinateHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(Values.mTextureCoordinateHandle, Values.COORDS_PER_VERTEX_TEXTURE, 
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                Values.fullStride, 0);


        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureOfBody); 
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(Values.mTheActualTexture, 0);


    GLES20.glUniform4fv(Values.mColorHandle, 1, colorOfBody, 0);


        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(Values.mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        // Draw the square
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo[0]);
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, drawOrder.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(Values.mTextureCoordinateHandle);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(Values.mPositionHandle);


        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
}
```

The shaders are loaded correctly. This are my shaders:

Vertex:

```
    uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
    attribute vec4 vPosition;
    attribute vec2 TexCoordinate;
    varying vec2 TexCoordinateGLFS;

    void main()
    {
        TexCoordinateGLFS = TexCoordinate;

        gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * newPosition ;
    }
```

Fragment:

```
    precision mediump float;
    uniform sampler2D theActualTexture;
    uniform vec4 vColor;
    varying vec2 TexCoordinateGLFS;

    void main() 
    {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(theActualTexture, TexCoordinateGLFS) * vColor;
    }
```

Some variables:

```
public static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
public static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX_TEXTURE = 2;

public static final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;
public static final int textureStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX_TEXTURE * 4;
public static final int fullStride = (COORDS_PER_VERTEX + COORDS_PER_VERTEX_TEXTURE) * 4;
```

EDIT:
This is the new VBO construct:

```
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((squareCoords.length + TextureCoords.length) * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
        vertexBuffer.put(TextureCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);


GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, vbo, 0);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer.capacity() * BYTES_PER_FLOAT,
                    vertexBuffer, GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

And here I draw:

```
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(Values.mPositionHandle, Values.COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                Values.vertexStride, 0);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(Values.mTextureCoordinateHandle, Values.COORDS_PER_VERTEX_TEXTURE, 
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                Values.textureStride, squareCoords.length);
```

squareCoords.length == 12; (3 coords for each vertice(x, y, z) -> 4 * 3 = 12)

Comment: This looks nasty ``ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())``, should you use byte size instead?

Comment: well... it worked ok before adding vbo, so I don't think the problem is there. The only things that I changed are: adding the vbo, and in the render class: bindBuffer. That's all that has changed.

Comment: Oh, I'm not exactly expecting this fixed the problem but am more surprised it compiles at all  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted it would seem you overwrite your position coordinates with your texture coordinates. Generally you will need as many buffers as you have arrays, so you need a separate buffer for the texture coordinates in your case. A more elegant solution is to merge the 2 mentioned arrays into 1 interleaved array, push it to a single VBO and use the stride when setting the vertex and texture coordinate pointers.

This is a total no-go:

```
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer.capacity() * 4, vertexBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TextureCoordinateBuffer.capacity() * 4, TextureCoordinateBuffer, GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

as you bind the same buffer twice and push data to the GPU so in the end all that is left there are texture coordinates (actually the code probably produces a single pixel image somewhere on your screen depending on your matrices)

Comment: I know that would be more elegant but I don't really know how to do that in java. In my desktop version which I wrote in c++, I just created a struct which contained all the information and after that I just call "4 * sizeof(dataBuffer)". Maybe if you could give a few hints. Btw I tried with 2 buffers and it worked like a charm, only instead of seeing a square I see triangles. What I changed is: glGenBuffers(2, vbo, 0) and: glBindBuffer(gl_array_buffer, vbo[0]) - for vertices, and vbo[1] for texture coordinates, and I changed when I created the vbo and at render time

Comment: Well in your case you can create 1 float array with interleaved coordinates and put it into 1 VBO, setting up stride. Or you can put both of your arrays into 1 byte buffer, put it into a single VBO and set offset for the second one. Also you can create some vertex object and use it more or less the same as in c++. As for the triangles problem you seem to have a strange combination of indices and triangle strip. You use 6 indices with triangle strip, that makes 4 triangles. Use without indices or set triangles (no strip)

Comment: I changed from triangle strip to triangle fan and it works well now with 2 vbos, but I am still trying to put both vertices and texture coordinates in the same vbo, but I can't get the offset right for the texture coordinates. The objects are drawn where they are supposed to be, but the texture is scrambled which makes me think it doesn't get the right texture coords. I made an EDIT with the newly added code.

Comment: BTW, are there vertex array objects in android opengl es 2.0? I searched over the web and found only for iOS. And if there are, can you point me to a tutorial or something?

Comment: Well, the offset will probably have to be in bytes, so try length*4 there (as in 4 = sizeof(float)). I wouldn't know about how to make a VAO on android, sorry.